# Show that the following Hölder-continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus

Show that a function that satisfies $\|f(x) - f(y)\| \le 100\|x-y\|^{1/2}$ is continuous.

So I divided both sides by $\|x-y\|$ and took the limit as $x$ approaches $y$ and showed it goes to $0$. I understand that this is like showing the derivative goes to $0$ in one variable, but not sure what it means in $2$ variables.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi mmmmo, it's good that you're learning Latex. I've formatted your question. Please take the time to press "edit", so you can play around with the code. It'll help you learn.

Comment: No need to consider "derivative", and actually you cannot do that. Recall the definition of continuity of multivariate functions.

Comment: So I think i understand what I need to do, just set delta to right value to show that the limit exists and in this case it is pretty easy to do right? But for part two I have to show that if the exponent of 3/2 then the function is constant, in this case was my original approach correct?

Comment: You can without lack of generality pretend $y$ is fix and only let $x$ vary.

Answer (score 2):

If you divide both sides by $||x-y||$, you get : $\frac{||f(x) - f(y)||}{||x-y||} \leq 100 \times ||x-y||^{-\frac 12}$.

It is not obvious that the limit of the left hand side is zero, since the right hand side goes to infinity (note that the exponent is negative) , so you cannot conclude that the function is differentiable, and that its derivative is zero everywhere. Can you think of a counterexample? (Hint : use a scaled version of $||x||^{\alpha}$ for some desirable $\alpha$, so that the function is also not differentiable at zero).

If the exponent is $\frac 32$,  then indeed the function is differentiable by taking the limit and using squeeze theorem, since now the right hand side would have limit zero. As for the initial question, it is good enough to look for a $\delta$ given $\epsilon$. From the make of the function, one sees that if $\epsilon \geq 100 \delta^{\frac 12}$ we are done.